# How can URLs have a dot . at the end, e.g. www.bla.de.?

Tags: domains, url

I never believed URLs could have a period at the end, as in [`www.google.de.`](http://www.google.de.) (which obvious is not working).

However, [`www.youtu.be.`](http://youtu.be.) is working perfectly well. How did they manage that?

Comment: The trailing . [dot] is actually correct, but systems make the assumption for you generally at the DNS level. So any .com site would actually be google.com. and this in theory should work, however, it may be that a browser will not expect this and fail to package the request correctly or if they do, then the DNS you are using does not understand it correctly. It is unusual that a user actually uses the dot and by default it is not required by the user.

Comment: `www.google.de.` works fine for me.

Comment: It's DNS magic. `.` is the overlord TLD, then you have [gTLDs](https://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt) :)

Comment: Teechnically, this is not a URL but a hostname. An additional dot at the end of a URL (`http://example.com/path/file.` vs. `http://example.com/path/file`) *can* make a difference. For example, if the path translates to a file and the underlying OS and filesystem distinguishes `file.`from `file`. I guess I need not mention that `http://example.com/path/file?foo=bar.` and `http://example.com/path/file?foo=bar` are also very different. urls

Comment: It's also possible that the web server is not configured to accept connections destined for that hostname.  When web servers using name-based virtual hosting process a `Host` header from an incoming request, there is no guarantee that it will treat it as if the `.` was not there.  I just verified that with a site I am running on Amazon S3.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

From [here](http://www.dns-sd.org/trailingdotsindomainnames.html)

> It's a little-known fact, but fully-qualified (unambiguous) DNS domain
>   names have a dot at the end. People running DNS servers usually know
>   this (if you miss the trailing dots out, your DNS configuration is
>   unlikely to work) but the general public usually doesn't. A domain
>   name that doesn't have a dot at the end is not fully-qualified and is
>   potentially ambiguous. This was documented in the DNS specification,
>   RFC 1034, way back in 1987:
>
> Since a complete domain name ends with the root label, this leads to a
>   printed form which ends in a dot.  We use this property to distinguish
>   between:
>
> - a character string which represents a complete domain name
>      (often called "absolute").  For example, "poneria.ISI.EDU."
> - a character string that represents the starting labels of a
>      domain name which is incomplete, and should be completed by
>      local software using knowledge of the local domain (often
>      called "relative").  For example, "poneria" used in the
>      ISI.EDU domain.

The source of this content continues to explain this in more detail.

Comment: Not only does the general public not know this, but I commonly see email validators that explicitly disallow a trailing dot.

Comment: @Kevin as well they should, both RFC2822 and RFC5322 prohibit a trailing period. They define the domain part as dot-atom, which is one more more atoms (an atom being one or more characters from an alphabet given in the RFC) separated by periods. See RFC5322 §3.4.1 and §3.2.3

Answer (score 54):

Hostnames without a trailing dot are potentially ambiguous. A trailing dot means that the hostname is fully qualified and may not be relative to the local search domain.

Imagine you are a student of the (fictive) Example University which has the second-level domain `example.edu`. Inside the university's campus network you can omit the `.example.edu` suffix for ease and lazyness. So if you want to surf to `www.example.edu` and are on-campus, you just have to surf to `www` and it works.

Now imagine the university has an institute for artificial intelligence ("AI") and their website is hosted on `www.ai.example.edu`. If you're on-campus, surfing to `www.ai` will suffice since you can omit the `.example.edu` suffix.

So far, so good. But now you want to surf to the "Offshore Information Services" company, which runs Anguilla's top-level domain `.ai`. Their website is at http://www.ai/ — but if you enter that URL into your web browser while being on campus, you'll land on the website of the institute for artificial intelligence instead.

So you need to tell the web browser that you really want to go to the website with the top-level domain `.ai` and not to the one with your university's subdomain `.ai.example.edu`. That's where the dot is important, because http://www.ai./ will always work independent of the local DNS search domain.

Analogous to the dots between the different domain levels, the last dot represents the root of the DNS, i.e. it states that the word before that dot is a top-level domain and no domain relative to the search domain.

Comment: -1 No modern browser treats hostnames with dots as unqualified.

Comment: It isn't the browser that does that, it is the DNS resolver.    The DNS resolver on my computer is set to use a domain name as the "search domain" which causes this behavior.  It is an operating system setting, not a browser setting.

Comment: Unfortunately for the students of Example University, adding the trailing . often confuses various vhosting configurations, and it'll stop working for any absolute links (which a lot of sites also use, too).

Comment: @fluffy: Yes, of course, if the web server uses virtual host configurations, those shortened hostnames must be listed in the vhost configuration, too.

Comment: @kinokijuf: I'd consider such behaviour a bug. The browser hasn't to decided if I want to use the searchdomain feature of my DNS resolver or not.

Comment: @XTaran Yep, but whether the www.ai.example.edu site has its vhosts configured correctly or not, the DNS resolution will still screw up if `www.ai` has an absolute link to `http://www.ai/something`, and if the `www.ai` server's httpd doesn't understand `www.ai.` as a configured host for some reason, you still can't browse it as `http://www.ai./` either.

Comment: @fluffy: Correct wrt. to absolute links with full host name but without trailing dot. Wrt. if `www.ai.` needs to be listed in www.ai's vhost config: I've never tried if that's really necessary, but I'd expect that at least Apache handles trailing dots automatically (by stripping them for vhost name matching).

Comment: @XTaran I've verified that Apache does automatically support trailing dots, but there are other webservers out there that might not be so smart. Which was why I raised the point.

Comment: Doesn't the search domain work the other way raouns? On input `www.ai`, the resolver first tries to find `www.ai.` and only if that fails it appends the search domain(s) one by one and tries to find `www.ai.example.edu.`instead? `

Comment: @Hagen: No, on input `www.ai.` it will never try to append the search domain. That's what the trailing dot does.

Comment: I don't think there's any need to obfuscate such a famous academic institution. :)

Comment: @XTaran What does your No refer to? My comment dealt only with `www.ai` and not with `www.ai.` as input

Comment: @Hagen: Ah, sorry, misinterpreted the comma behind "www.ai" as dot. AFAIK it first honours the search domain as `host` and friends do, too.

Answer (score -5):

I think the answer is that most Internet tools just drop the `.` or treat it as *extra path information*.

Note that this is a very tricky illusion. `youtu.be` is not `youtube.be`.  Not sure, but this might be abuse.

Comment: `youtu.be` is a domain by youtube. It's used for shorter links for example when sharing or embedding videos.

Comment: note to @CareyB: that's probably okay, since 'youtu.be' is youtube's no-longer-that-recently-introduced URL shortener for youtube videos; just pop on the ID of a video (e.g. for a video [hmm, by someone that apparently does NOT understand CC-BY-SA] about FQDN naming mentioning that the root domain is an empty string, and thus leaves a dot at the end, located at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qHAb3Foa1Nw you can use https://youtu.be/qHAb3Foa1Nw

Comment: -1; incorrect, and the youtu.be/youtube.be distinction has nothing to do with this issue at all.