# Redirect URL with multiple trailing dots and trailing slashes using .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, redirects, trailing-slash

I need to fire `301` redirection
from `example.com...` to `example.com`
and `example.com//////` to `example.com`

Here is my code:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /([^\?\ .]*)\.(?:\?|\ |$)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]
```

It does not work.

And here is my *.htaccess* file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /([^\?\ .]*)\.(?:\?|\ |$)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Do you mean redirect URLs with any number of dots and slashes, regardless of whether they contain filenames between them, just to your root domain? Does that include URLs ending or containing filenames with certain file extensions, or all file extensions? It might help to explain what you're trying to accomplish by explaining why you want to do this.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this one:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //|..
  RewriteRule ^.*$ /$0 [R=301,L,NE]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

The dot(s) at the end of the hostname (ie. [a fully qualified domain](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/73934/how-can-urls-have-a-dot-at-the-end-e-g-www-bla-de)) will appear in the `HTTP_HOST` server variable (not `THE_REQUEST`) and the multiple slashes at the start of the URL-path will be present in the `THE_REQUEST` variable (like you are using), so you will need at least two rules. Try something like:

```
# Remove trailing dot(s) on the hostname
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.$
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Remove multiple slashes at the start of the URL-path
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ //+
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

The `RewriteCond` directive simply checks for multiple slashes at the start of the URL-path (after the first *space* in `THE_REQUEST` variable). The redirect then relies on the fact that Apache automatically truncates multiple slashes in the URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* and uses this (`$1` backreference) in the *substitution*.

NB: Make sure you clear your browser cache before testing as any erroneous 301s are likely to have been cached.

*Aside:* I think a hostname with *more than one* trailing dot is strictly invalid - it will fail to resolve and never actually reach your server. (?) If the request is being made from a browser then the browser will probably truncate the multiple trailing dots - leaving just one (ie. fully qualified) - before making the request.

Reference:

- [How can URLs have a dot . at the end, e.g. www.bla.de.?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/73934/how-can-urls-have-a-dot-at-the-end-e-g-www-bla-de)
- [How should websites handle hostname with trailing dot?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/73989/how-should-websites-handle-hostname-with-trailing-dot)